# Tensorflow get shape from Graph Def in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to get shape of input tensor in C++ before I do any inference calls. So I can do it only from Graph Def.

I'm trying like:

```
 auto att = graph_def.node(i).attr();
 att["shape"].PrintDebugString();
 Tensor tensor;
 std::cerr << tensor.FromProto(att["shape"].tensor()) << std::endl;
```

And it returs false. While PrintDebugString prints:

> shape {   dim {
>       size: -1   }   dim {
>       size: 1024   }   dim {
>       size: 1024   }   dim {
>       size: 3   } }

So all I need is to get that 1024x1024x3. I'm not very familiar with Protobuf protocol and for me is totally unclear how to do that.

Comment: I don't have the C++ API installed, so this suggestion might be wrong, but this operation will give you the size of the considered dimension in Python: `graphDef.node[i].attr['shape'].dim[j].size`. Note that `node`, `shape`, `dim` are google `protobuf::Message` derivatives.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to do it this way:

```
auto shape = graph_def.node().Get(0).attr().at("shape").shape();
for (int i = 0; i < shape.dim_size(); i++) {
    std::cout << shape.dim(i).size()<<std::endl;
}
```

In my case it was: 1 128 128 3